# Android: How to send http request via service every 5 seconds

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, android-service

I want to request json data from webservices after every 5 seconds. As I don't want to show that to user so I'm doing this stuff in Service. There is no error in the code but its not showing any output in the Log as expected.

Here is the code:

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    final String driverId = intent.getStringExtra("DriverId");

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // making request to url and getting respose
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url + "?cno=" + driverId + "&lat=0&lon=79");

            Log.e("ServicesClass", "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                String temp = jsonStr;
                String finals = temp.replace("<string xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">", "");
                Log.e(TAG, "Response from url at Service Class: " + jsonStr);

            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Response from url at Service Class: " + jsonStr);
            }
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Code for makeServiceCall:

```
public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl){

        String response = null;

        try {

            URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

             //read the response
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            response = convertStreamToString(in);
        }catch (MalformedURLException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "MalformedException: " +e.getMessage());
        }catch (ProtocolException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Protocal Exception: " +e.getMessage());
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " +e.getMessage());
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " +e.getMessage());
        }
        return response;
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is){

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){

                sb.append(line).append('\n');
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Can anyone help to figure out from code where can be error?

Comment: You can use intent service for that and you won't be needing asyncTask for that

Comment: I used intentService, check edited post, but same issue exists.

Comment: what's the issue

Comment: As you can see i'm logging Log.e("ServicesClass", "Response from url: " + jsonStr); but in logcat there are not logs visible, that means code is not executing or something else i'm not able to figure out

Comment: first of all get rid of Handler() and directly call make service call

Comment: Same without handler too. Service is being called but its not showing any log or response

Comment: how do you know the service is being called? Have you tried setting breakpoints and stepping through the code?

Comment: @DavidWasser Yes i have code in main activity to test if service is running or not. I debugged the service code its getting url and parameters. but not showing log to able to know if it called server and did the job done.

Comment: Add logging in `makeServiceCall()` or set breakpoint and step through it. You need to narrow down where the problem is. There isn't anything obvious from the code you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

Using Alarm manager set repeating alarm.

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, RepeatingService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, 5000, 5000, pendingIntent);
```

RepeatingService use IntentService because when job is finished its stopped automatically.

```
class RepeatingService extends IntentService{

 override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
   // do your stuff like async or anyother task.
}

}
```

Comment: Please check edited post, I used intentService but same issue exists.